# How to serialize a form that contains jQuery ajax loaded fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

This is the main form:

```
<div>
     <form method="post" class="register" id="wiz-config">
        <!-- HTML -->
        <input type="radio" value="187" name="group-1" id="product-187" class="aselector" >
        <input type="radio" value="188" name="group-1" id="product-188" class="aselector" >
        <!-- HTML -->
        <!-- Other ajax fields -->

     </form>
</div>
```

Other ajax fields are loaded via ajax.

The problem is that if I use

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
var str = jQuery( "#wiz-config" ).serialize();
console.log(str);
});
```

it returns is "empty". Why?

Comment: Ajax has nothing to do with your issue ;)

Comment: No it's o typo here.  sorry. The original code has the #

Comment: Can you update your code to show this.

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript code.

Comment: If you call your script on document ready, ajax elements are loaded and anyway radio inputs in your code aren't checked (so they aren't serialized). You have to serialize form once you submit it

Comment: Is it completely empty, or are some results in there? Could you add the contents that are written to the console?

Answer (score 2):

You've just forgotten to put [the selector #](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_id.asp) :

```
$( "#wiz-config" ).serialize();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery selection is wrong. You need `#` because you are trying to select by the Id.

```
$("#wiz-config" ).serialize();
```

> **ID Selector (“#id”)** :  Selects a single element with the given id
>   attribute.

Or if you have only one form in your page, you may try this as well to get the form

```
var _form = $("form");
console.log(_form);
var serializedVersion = _form.serialize();
```

**EDIT :** As per the comment, you are not getting the dynamically added form elements. The only reason i can think of is, You might not be giving the `name` attribute and it's value to these dynamically added form elements. `serialize` method will serialize only those elements with a valid `name` attribute.

The below should work without any problems.

```
$(function(){

   var newItems="<input name='place' type='text' />";

   $("#wiz-config").append(newItems);

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/tisaritede/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.

Comment: But in this way it not returns the fields loaded by ajax.

Comment: @AlexRighetto See my updated answer and the jsbin sample.

Comment: @Shyju Good point but as a side note, non checked radio inputs aren't serialized and OP is calling it on document ready

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an element not an ID.

```
$("wiz-config").serialize();
```

Is looking for an element, such as p, div, etc.

To call an item by ID, you need to add a leading #:

```
$("#wiz-config").serialize();
```